# how to define a copy method in django models

Tags: django, python-3.x, model

i have three models for a blog , shown blow:

```
class Author(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    body = models.TextField()   
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def copy():
        pass

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
```

i want to define a **copy()** method for BlogPost model that copies a BlogPost instance with copieng related **comment** instances . how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the related comments of a given BlogPost instance and make a copy of each comment by nulling its `pk` attribute, then assign the `blog_post` foreign key to `self` and save.

```
def copy(self, post):
    for comment in post.comment_set.all():
        comment.pk = None
        comment.blog_post = self
        comment.save()
```